# Grafana worldmap panel with Influxdb

Tags: grafana

I am struggling to get the worldmap panel working with influxdb.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem like you. Can you show how your data in influxdb looks alike ?

Comment: "gcpvh3zgu992" -- geohash,  16 -- totalpass

Comment: have you tried a lower precision ? I remember that the max precision with a elasticsearch datasource is 7. So maybe try with a precision of 5 to be sure thats not the problem

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: I tried the same query locally and it didn't work for me either. If you change the alias on the geohash field to something else e.g. `alias(geohash)` to `alias(test)` does it work then? Will investigate more and see if I can find the problem.

Comment: Is geohash a field or a tag? Does this query work in other panels (a table panel for example)?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have saved geohash as a tag.

If I run your query in a table panel, then I get two fields in the result called geohash and one of them is empty.

I think you can remove the `field(geohash)` from the `select` and get the result you want. (Or remove the `last` selector or change the alias so that there is no conflict between it and the group by).

[image]